# How to dynamically update a matplotlib table cell text

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

My code reads two files of numbers and plots them dynamically in a plot window on the upper part of the window. 
I also put a table below the plot.
I want to take the latest values as they are plotted and update cells in the table with those numbers.
The table gets updated on the screen the first time that the "set_text" is called, but what is displayed on the screen doesn't keep changing, even though the table is being updated.
What do I need to add to get the table to display the value as it updates it.

```
<snip>
def update_line(num, sdata, line1, d2data, line2, my_table):
    for i in range(0, num):
        line1.set_data(sdata[0, :num], sdata[1,:num])
        line2.set_data(d2data[0, :num], d2data[1,:num])
    tm.sleep(0.1)
    tmp = sdata[1, num]
    my_table._cells[(1, 1)]._text.set_text(tmp)
    return line1,line2, my_table,

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, 149, fargs=(d2data, f, d1data,l, the_table), interval=1, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

[This shows the resulting figure.  Note that the red/blue lines animate and draw over several seconds](http://postimg.org/image/knj0y7ehr/)

Comment: Too much code, too much text. Don't tell us what all you can do. Just please take your time to clearly state your QUESTION and to remove all the unnecessary code which is not relevant.

Comment: I've found working code in these forums to be very useful to beginners.  I thought I'd share back.
But fair enough...  the line setting the table cell near the bottom of the update_line function only seems to work the first time through

Comment: Please fix your question. It is not useful to anyone if you put mess to your QUESTION. Neither your boasting what you *can* do is useful to anyone. Edit your question as I told you - remove almost everything and leave there only what is relevant. Also state your quustion clearly in the question text, not in the comment.

Comment: Great edit! You have significantly improved your question. Now you follow the StackOverflow standards. I am removing back my original downvote.

Answer (score 11):

In principle the line `my_table._cells[(1, 1)]._text.set_text(tmp)` should update the table cell data. The reason it is not working here, is that `blitting` is used. It may help to just turn off blitting in the call to `FuncAnimation`: `blit=False`. If that doesn't solve the issue, one needs to do the animation manually using `fig.canvas.draw()` inside a loop.

Note that one should better not be using "private" attributes. Hence I would recommend

```
my_table.get_celld()[(1, 1)].get_text().set_text(tmp)
```